# What's the planet where this duel happened in the Obi Wan Kenobi series?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

After watching the *Obi Wan Kenobi* series finale (episode 6), after all the emotional turmoil that it caused, I was writing a review and realized I don't know the name of the planet where the final Vader - Kenobi duel happened (at least until the Deathstar in *A New Hope* for now)

Is there any information on it? I only did a quick Google search but came up empty. Is there a source or something where they mention it?

Comment: Not sure it's ever named on screen,

Comment: Everything I've seen refers to a "barren planet" or a "barren moon", no names.

Comment: @Valorum So was it the same as the first duel seen in episode 3 of the series? The links say it was only featured in episodes 2, 3 and 4...not 6

Comment: It is referred to as desolate moon, even though its terrain looks like Oba-Diah.

Comment: How far could a ship with no light speed capabilities possibly travel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not planet, it's a <s>space-station</s> moon. In fact, one so bleak and desolate that it doesn't have a name, according to the [Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/barren-moon).

> **BARREN MOON**
>
> On **a nameless moon not far from Jabiim**, Darth Vader and Ben Kenobi
> meet for a critical duel. The satellite of rocky spires and yawning
> crevasses becomes a historic site, as the former Jedi master emerges
> victorious and accepts that his friend, Anakin Skywalker, is truly
> gone.
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.starwars.com/databank/barren-moon</sup></sub>

Comment: really, barren moon?

Comment: @shanu - Not everything has to have a name.

Comment: Yup. It's disappointing but it seems to be the official name/no-name, so I'm accepting this answer.